# Varchar value need to be used in numeric field in where condition

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

how to pass a varchar variable in a numeric field .
I have a variable v_num which is varchar2 format ,I want to pass this value in numeric column field num1 in where condition i.e select * from numerics where num1 =v_num ;which currently is showing error.

Comment: The [plsqldeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsqldeveloper/info) tag is for questions about the desktop application [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer), not for Oracle development in general.

Comment: An error message and [test case reproducing the error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `TO_NUMBER` function:

```
select *
from numerics
where num1 = to_number(v_num)
```

This will, of course, fail if you pass e.g. `A2` or `Femi` to `v_num`.

---

Demo:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    v_num varchar2(10) := '3000';  --> varchar2, but '3000' can be converted to number
  3    l_cnt number;
  4  begin
  5    select count(*)
  6      into l_cnt
  7      from emp
  8      where sal = to_number(v_num);             --> TO_NUMBER
  9    dbms_output.put_line('Result: ' || l_cnt);
 10  end;
 11  /
Result: 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

---

```
SQL> declare
  2    v_num varchar2(10) := 'x3000';  --> 'x3000' can NOT be converted to number
  3    l_cnt number;
  4  begin
  5    select count(*)
  6      into l_cnt
  7      from emp
  8      where sal = to_number(v_num);              --> TO_NUMBER
  9    dbms_output.put_line('Result: ' || l_cnt);
 10  end;
 11  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at line 5


SQL>
```

Comment: I have used the same but its giving an error ORA-1722- invalid number

Comment: Did you read the last sentence I wrote? I edited the answer and posted demo which shows what happens. Have a look.